# How to Laravel controller multi guard access methods?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to call middle-ware in constructor of my controller.

My PostController class is below

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware( ['auth:admin', ['only'=> ['store', 'update']]], ['auth:client', ['only'=> ['index', 'view']]]);
    }    
}
```

Please suggestion or correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way do it in routes

```
Route::post('path', 'IndexController@store')->middleware(['auth:admin']);
Route::get('path', 'IndexController@index')->middleware(['auth:client]);
```

Or in group, for example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function ($route) {
   $route->post('storePath', 'IndexController@store');
   $route->put('updatePath', 'IndexController@update');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the middleware function multiple times.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin', ['only'=> ['store', 'update']])
        $this->middleware('auth:client', ['only'=> ['index', 'view']]);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes  i try this, but when i access client guard method it not work, admin guard return error Unauthenticated message